# Fujitsu laptop turns on but nothing happens

Tags: laptop, motherboard

I've recently got an Fujitsu Siemens Amilo laptop that turns on, but doesn't show anything both on it's screen and any external monitor (it doesn't do anything at all) .

Known issues:

- there is a blown surface mounted capacitor near the power jack.
- the CMOS battery was flat

What i have tried:

- i did a hard reset (holding the power button for a minute)
- i tried 3 different RAM sticks
- i replaced the CMOS battery
- i tried to power it on without all other peripherals (DVD-ROM, hard drive, ...)
- i removed the CPU from the socket and it does the same

Could the motherboard be fried ?

Comment: My recent fortune cookie tell me that "Everything might be repaired - it is just matter of price" ;P You should go to service...

Comment: It does not worth the service, because i bought the whole thing (including the good battery) for $8. The seller told me that it was for spare parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've exhausted the most likely causes. Likely dead MoBo/CPU/GFX, or more blown caps along with the one you've identified.